# by using python getting images form website

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, web

I'm trying to get images from website but getting an error.

here is the code:

```
url = 'http://www.techradar.com/news/internet/web/12-best-places-to-get-free-images-for-your-site-624818'
image = urlopen(url).read()
patFinderImage = re.compile('.jpg')
imgUrl = re.findall('<img src="(.*)" />', url)
outfile = open('abc.htm', 'wb')
outfile.write(imgUrl)
outfile.close
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joh\workspace\new2\newnewurl.py", line 14, in <module>
    outfile.write(imgUrl)
TypeError: 'list' does not support the buffer interface
```

Comment: `re.findall` returns a list, how do you want it to be printed to the file, one result per line, with a delimiter or just all results concatenated directly one after another?

Comment: actually i want all images yes one result per line with their names. like image name is /link/baloon.jpg so it must store with its name.

Comment: @user3299370: Put that information into the question. Ideally, show some (very small) sample input and the expected output.

Comment: As a side note: `outfile.close` doesn't do anything; you can to _call_ the `close` method, not just refer to it, as in `outfile.close()`. Or, better, use a `with` statement instead of an explicit `close` call.

Comment: Also you might want to search `image` instead of `url`...

Comment: right now I'm just focusing on this error later will compile with the other part of code. consider your suggestions.

Comment: yes Nabla i need images only

Comment: @user3299370: My answer explains why you get this error. There are three different problems all getting in the way. If you don't want to actually fix those problems, or understand them, and just want to eliminate this error, that's easy: just don't ever call `outfile.write` and it won't happen…

Answer (score 0):

[`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list of found strings. So, `imgUrl` is a list.

You can't [`write`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) a list of strings to a file, only a string. Hence the error message.

If you want to write out the string representation of the list (which is easy, but unlikely to be useful), you can do this:

```
outfile.write(str(imgUrl))
```

If you want to write just the first URL, which is a string, you can:

```
outfile.write(imgUrl[0])
```

If you want to write all of the URLs, one on each line:

```
for url in imgUrl:
    outfile.write(url + '\n')
```

Or, since it's HTML and the whitespace doesn't matter, you can write them all run together:

```
outfile.write(''.join(imgUrl))
```

---

You then have a *second* problem. For some reason, you've opened the file in binary mode. I don't know why you're doing this, but if you do, you can only write `bytes` to the file, not strings. But you don't have a list of `bytes`, you have have a list of strings. So, you need to `encode` those strings into bytes. For example:

```
for url in imgUrl:
    outfile.write(url.encode('utf-8') + b'\n')
```

Or—much better—just don't open the file in binary mode:

```
outfile = open('abc.htm', 'w')
```

If you want to specify an explicit encoding, you can still do that without using binary mode:

```
outfile = open('abc.htm', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

---

You may also have a *third* problem. From your comments, it appears that `imgUrl[0]` gives you an `IndexError`. That means that it's empty. Which means your regex is not actually finding any URLs to write in the first place. In that case, you obviously can't successfully write them out (unless you're expecting an empty file).

And the reason (or at least *a* reason) the regex is not finding anything is that you're not actually searching the downloaded HTML (which you've stored in `image`) but the URL to that HTML (which you've stored in `url`):

```
imgUrl = re.findall('<img src="(.*)" />', url)
```

… and obviously there are no matches for your regexp in the string `'http://www.techradar.com/news/internet/web/12-best-places-to-get-free-images-for-your-site-624818'`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joh\workspace\new2\newnewurl.py", line 14, in <module>
    outfile.write(str(imgUrl))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
____________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joh\workspace\new2\newnewurl.py", line 14, in <module>
    outfile.write(imgUrl[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joh\workspace\new2\newnewurl.py", line 14, in <module>
    outfile.write(imgUrl + '\n')
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
___________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joh\workspace\new2\newnewurl.py", line 14, in <module>
    outfile.write(''.join(imgUrl))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: the above are the errors generates according to your suggestions. respectively.

Comment: @user3299370: Do not try to paste tracebacks into comments here; it makes them unreadable. But I can guess what the problem is; I'll edit to explain.

Comment: @abarnert Your last paragraph: Actually OP is simply searching the wrong string `url` instead of `image`.

Comment: @Nabla: Ah, good catch; thanks, I'll edit the answer. No guarantee that this is the _only_ problem, but it obviously won't work without that fix. :)